# jQuery Looping Through Background Images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a jQuery function that I'm trying to use to cycle through different background images fading in and out. For some reason it is only changing from the default background image to the second one (contact_banner) and then back to the same one again.

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm sure it's something simple but I can't seem to work it out.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

function slider(){

    $('#cover').delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);
    $('#cover').css("background-image", "url('images/classes-cover.jpg')");
    $('#cover').fadeIn(1000);

    $('#cover').delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);
    $('#cover').css("background-image", "url('images/contact_banner.png')");
    $('#cover').fadeIn(1000, slider);
}   
slider();
});
```

Comment: Your code blocks are running simultaneously.

Comment: try this. http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/slider/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery fade is asynchronous. Use callbacks to fire the next event once the first is done.

```
$('#cover').fadeIn(1000, function() { $('#cover').fadeIn(1000, ... ); });
```

Have a look at this fiddle I've prepared for you http://jsfiddle.net/xu7sbofv/.

The important thing to understand is that the function does not block on fadeIn() or delay() because the calls are asynchronous. This is why you must supply callback functions.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I see what you mean, I wasn't aware it was asynchronous. I don't quite follow how to achieve it with the code snippet you've written though?

Comment: Please see the edits I've made to my post above and the fiddle I've created.

Comment: Thank you that's really useful to help me understand the process

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find a solution to this, a bit of a neater implementation too:

```
var imgSrcs =[
    "images/class-banner/running-group_banner2.png",
    "images/class-banner/running-group_banner3.png",
    "images/class-banner/running-group_banner1.png",
];

$('#cover').delay(1000).fadeIn(1000, animateBackground());

function animateBackground() {

    window.setTimeout(function(){

        var url = imgSrcs[imgSrcs.push(imgSrcs.shift()) - 1];

        $('#cover').delay(4000).fadeOut(1000, function(){

            $(this).css("background-image", "url(" + url + ")")

        }).fadeIn(1000, animateBackground())

    });
}
```